# mkdir create directory in current users directory - bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p user_records
```

I want to create a directory `user_records` in the current user's directory. How do I achieve this? I tried adding `sudo` in front of `mkdir` but that does not create the directory in the desired location.

Comment: What goes wrong if you try? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Am I guessing correctly that you're trying to create the dir in a home folder of a user you're not currently logged in as? Because I just tried that and it works, so I'm curious if you have any more information about what goes wrong.

Comment: I am missing the exect errormessage. When `sudo echo $PWD` shows the correct dir, you can try `sudo mkdir -p "${PWD}/user_records"`.

Comment: I think you are mixing up the issue and solution, as mentioned. The `-p` argument is used to create an entire hierarchical directory structure. But this seems to be a permission issue where the user which you run `mkdir` as does not have write permission in the target directory.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to access the user directory with `~`, so you could try:

```
mkdir -p ~/user_records
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the `-p` option is not necessary here. It is only useful if you want to create a hierarchy of directories. Example: if you want to create a "baz" directory inside a "bar" directory, inside a "foo" directory, inside the current directory, you will use the following command: `mkdir -p foo/bar/baz`.

In your Bash script, you have 3 simple solutions:

**cd**

```
#!/bin/bash
cd
mkdir user_records
```

**~**

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir ~/user_records
```

**$HOME**

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir "$HOME/user_records"
```

Comment: But that can't be the cause of the OP's problem. -p is perfectly fine to use, even if you're creating a single dir only one deep.

Comment: @MrLister You are perfectly right, but I like the KISS principle. :)

Comment: Which is never a bad idea, but in this case it won't solve the OP's problem ;)

Comment: Indeed, my first paragraph was just an observation. But if you read on, the solution is pretty clear... :D

Comment: The `-p` option has the advantage of not throwing an error in case the directory already exists. So it’s useful even when you don’t need to create a hierarchy.